# LiveData and Coroutines - Property must be initialized or abstract

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, coroutine

I am trying to use LiveData and Coroutines together in MVVM, and I may be missing something simple.

```
class WeatherViewModel (
    private val weatherRepository: ForecastRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    var weather: LiveData<Weather>;

    /**
     * Cancel all coroutines when the ViewModel is cleared.
     */
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            weather = weatherRepository.getWeather()
        }

    }

}
```

But I am getting `Property must be initialized or be abstract` on assigning the `weather` in the `init` function.
I am assuming this is the case because I am using coroutines `viewModelScope.launch`.

```
override suspend fun getWeather(): LiveData<Weather> {
    return withContext(IO){
       initWeatherData()
       return@withContext weatherDao.getWeather()
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `weather` property as [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables):

```
private lateinit var weather: LiveData<String>
```

Or make it **[nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)**:

```
private var weather: LiveData<String>? = null
```

If you're sure that the property will be initialized before you first use it use `lateinit` otherwise make it **nullable**.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature as follow:

```
var weather =  MutableLiveData<Weather>();
```

Plus, you should return just a `Weather` object and not a LiveData<>
so you should change the signature of `getWeather()` to return `: Weather`.

Comment: that doesn't sound right. That would mean I would be assigning a `Weather` object to a `MutableLiveData<Weather>`. I only need the `LiveData` that Room or Retrofit is providing in the Repository.

Comment: No, you will assign the Weather Object that Room or Retrofit will provide to `weather.value`

Comment: but taking the value out of a `LiveData` and putting it into a `MutableLiveData` will defeat the purpose of using `LiveData`. I am using databinding and want the value to be automatically updated as the values changes.

Comment: You should use `LiveData` in this way for View updating, not for ViewModel/Presenter--Room/Retrofit interaction

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, by default, every property must be initialized (even the nullable types with null).

You can initialize your property directly in the declaration or within init block.

Problem with your code is that the launch function can keep on going after your init block is done, and the compiler knows this. So, it's telling you - don't count on it.

As previously said, you can use **lateinit** to state that you'll initialize your property later, if you're sure it will happen before you're gonna use it.

Answer (score -1):

`weather` must be initialized with instantiation of the class because you have not said that it can be null, and you are not using the `lateinit` keyword (which you should not in this case).

`launch` is an async coroutine call that returns immediately, but will be executed at some point in the future. This means that your `init` block completes and returns without `weather` being initialized.

Use `runBlocking` instead. This will block until you have the result in the `init` block and so guarantee that weather is not null on instantiation. Something like:

```
init {
    weather = runBlocking {
        weatherRepository.getWeather()
    }
}
```

You can pass which ever coroutine context dispatcher to `runBlocking` as well.

Or - stick with the coroutine, but join in the init block like:

```
init {
    val job = viewModelScope.launch {
        weather = weatherRepository.getWeather()
    }
    job.join()
}
```

Comment: won't the main thread be blocked until it is returned with this method?

Comment: @Alan which ever thread this class gets instantiated on will be blocked until the object is instantiated (including all of its non-null variables). yes. If you want to return immediately and set the `weather` type to `LiveData<Weather>?` and have the field set at some later stage fine, but I suspect it would be useless before that variable was set, and then you would have to do null checks every time you wanted to use it. Kotlin is null safe.

Comment: @Alan you are trying to do do conflicting things - have a variable that is not null, and also instantiate it asynchronously on construction of the object. If `weatherRepository.getWeather()` is not a suspending function that must be called in a coroutine context then just do `weather = weatherRepository.getWeather()`. My understanding is that your class cannot do anything it needs to do until it has that instance.